# Not Found for an API route

Tags: javascript, next.js

In my Next.js project I have `main/app/api/worker-callback/route.ts` file:

```js
import { NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

type ResponseData = {
    error?: string
};

export async function POST(req: Request, res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>) {
    if (req.headers.get('Authorization') !== process.env.BACKEND_SECRET!) {
        res.status(403).json({ error: "Allowed only by backend" });
        // return Response.json({ error: "Allowed only by backend" }, { status: 403 });
    }
    return NextResponse.json({});
}
```

But when I query it, I get error 404. Why?

```
curl -d '' -v -o/dev/null -H "accept: application/json" http://localhost:3000/api/worker-callback
...
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
...
```

Note that HTML pages in `main/app` work just fine. I build it by the `cd main && next build` command.

Comment: Apparently, I just didn't compile my code. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 2):

It appears the problem is that you are sending a GET request instead of the POST which you have defined in your API. You would want to add `-X POST` to send a POST request.

Comment: `-d ''` flag automatically switches to POST.

Comment: Have you tried making the request in the Postman? Just to be sure

Comment: The error was that I didn't compile my code. Dot.

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues:

1. Routing Configuration: Confirm the
   `main/app/api/worker-callback/route.ts` file is in the correct
   directory (`pages/api` IIRC) for Next.js to recognize it as an API route.
2. Function Export: You may need to try exporting as default (`export default async function...`), instead of the named POST export.

Also double-check that the server is running, and the URL is correct, and that `next build` completes without errors.

Comment: In modern Next.js it is used `app/` instead of `pages/`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code snippets you have provided inside your question, there seem to be a multitude of issues with the route handler:

- Route handlers no longer receive the second `res` parameter.
- Route handlers should return a promise of type `NextResponse`.
- The syntax for the response inside the eager return is invalid.
- You were missing the `return` keyword inside the eager return

```js
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest): Promise<NextResponse> {
  if (request.headers.get("Authorization") !== process.env.BACKEND_SECRET!) {
    // should also be an instance of NextResponse and you were missing a return here
    return NextResponse.json({ error: "Allowed only by backend" }, { status: 403 });
  }

  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello from the backend" });
}
```

I have tested my code snipped locally and by adding my proposed changes it will work as desired. I strongly recommend you read the documentation on [route handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) since they changed quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function POST(req: Request, res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>) {
    if (req.headers.get('Authorization') !== process.env.BACKEND_SECRET!) {
        return Response.json({ message: 'Allowed only by backend' });
    } else {
        return Response.json({ message: 'Hello from Next.js!' })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the build script from the correct root folder?

Answer (score 0):

The **API route** file name should match the **HTTP** method that it handles, such as `get.ts`, `post.ts`, `put.ts`, etc. However, in your code, you are using `route.ts` as the file name, which is not a valid **HTTP** method. This may cause `Next.js` to not recognize the file as an API route and return a **404** error.

To fix this, you need to use the correct file name for the **API** route. You should rename the `route.ts` file to `post.ts`, since you are handling the **POST** method in your code.

For example, you can use the following command to rename the file:

```
mv main/app/api/worker-callback/route.ts main/app/api/worker-callback/post.ts
```

Then, you can query the API route using the same URL as before:

```
curl -d '' -v -o/dev/null -H "accept: application/json" http://localhost:3000/api/worker-callback
```

You should get a **200 OK** response if the request is authorized, or a **403 Forbidden** response if the request is not authorized.